# How to convert SQL query to query builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

controlens is a table in my database and entite, state are the fields of this table

```
SELECT a.entite, a.etat,  COUNT(a.etat) as nombre_toperform, b.nombre_performed,c.nombre_incompatible
FROM `controlens` a

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT entite,COUNT(etat) as nombre_performed from `controlens` WHERE etat like 'PERFORMED' GROUP BY entite, etat) b on a.entite = b.entite

LEFT JOIN ( SELECT entite,COUNT(etat) as nombre_incompatible from `controlens` WHERE etat like 'INCOMPATIBLE' GROUP BY entite, etat) c on a.entite = c.entite

WHERE a.etat like '%TOPERFORM%' 
GROUP BY a.entite, a.etat, b.nombre_performed,c.nombre_incompatible
```

Comment: This is the English version of Stackoverflow. Please post your question in English.

Comment: help me translate the sql query into the query builder query

Comment: Edit your question, and show us some code, where you tried to do this. 

We can't made all for you, and check how to post a question

Answer (score 0):

There are likely few ways in which you can accomplish this.  Here is one idea that might work (note: haven't fully tested, so it might need some tweaks):

```
$toPerform = '%TOPERFORM%';
$subQuery1 = 'SELECT entite,COUNT(etat) as nombre_performed from `controlens` WHERE etat like 'PERFORMED' GROUP BY entite, etat';
$subQuery2 = 'SELECT entite,COUNT(etat) as nombre_incompatible from `controlens` WHERE etat like 'INCOMPATIBLE' GROUP BY entite, etat';

DB::table('controlens as a')->select([
    'a.entite',
    'a.etat',
    DB::raw('COUNT(a.etat) AS nombre_toperform'),
    'b.nombre_performed',
    'c.nombre_incompatible'
])
->leftJoin(DB::raw("($subQuery1) as b"), 'a.entite', '=', 'b.entite')
->leftJoin(DB::raw("($subQuery2) as c"), 'a.entite', '=', 'c.entite')
->where('a.etat', $toPerform)
->groupBy('a.entite', 'a.etat', 'b.nombre_performed', 'c.nombre_incompatible');
```

Alternatively, you could try this package to see if it helps the cause:
[eloquent-subquery-magic](https://github.com/maksimru/eloquent-subquery-magic)

Beyond that, here are a few helpful articles that might point you in the correct direction:

> [subquery with join in
>   laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864202/subquery-with-join-in-laravel)
>
> [Laravel Fluent Query Builder Join with
>   subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079281/laravel-fluent-query-builder-join-with-subquery)
>
> [How to write this (left join, subquery ) in Laravel
>   5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677457/how-to-write-this-left-join-subquery-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: thanks cfnerd i have tested your answer it's a good help for me